# Constructors in Python

Tags: python, constructor

I need help in writing code for a Python constructor method.

This constructor method would take the following three parameters:

```
x, y, angle
```

What is an example of this?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it with [homework].

Comment: // , Would you be willing to improve this question, @hugh?

Answer (score 19):

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.angle = angle
```

The constructor is always written as a function called `__init__()`. It must always take as its first argument a reference to the instance being constructed. This is typically called `self`. The rest of the arguments are up to the programmer.

The `object` on the first line is the superclass, i.e. this says that `MyClass` is a subclass of `object`. This is normal for Python class definitions.

You access fields (members) of the instance using the `self.` syntax.

Comment: thanks if possible can someone explain it so i can understand it and learn it

Comment: Technically \_\_init\_\_ is not the constructor, \_\_new\_\_ is; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130644/what-is-the-difference-between-a-constructer-and-initializer-in-python The object already exists when \_\_init\_\_ is called, which initializes its fields.

Answer (score 6):

Constructors are declared with `__init__(self, other parameters)`, so in this case:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.angle = angle
```

You can read more about this here: [Class definition in python](http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

Answer (score 2):

See the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Answer (score -4):

```
class MyClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do initialization
```

Comment: Often a constructor may have extra parameters that should not be passed on to the parent(s) constructor

Comment: // , @giolekva Would you be willing to improve this'n?