# Decorator's classes cant change class variable

Tags: python, python-decorators

i have class hero

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.positive_effects = []
        self.negative_effects = []

        self.stats = {
            "HP": 128,
            "MP": 42,
        "SP": 100,

        "Strength": 15,
        "Perception": 4,
        "Endurance": 8,
        "Charisma": 2,
        "Intelligence": 3,
        "Agility": 8,
        "Luck": 1
    } 

def get_positive_effects(self):
    return self.positive_effects.copy()

def get_negative_effects(self):
    return self.negative_effects

def get_stats(self):
    return self.stats.copy()
```

i need to create decorator spell, for example:

```
class AbstractEffect(Hero):
    def __init__(self, base):
            self.base = base

    def get_stats(self):
            self.base.get_stats()   

    def get_positive_effects(self):
        self.base.get_positive_effects()

    def get_negative_effects(self):
        self.base.get_negative_effects()

class Berserk(AbstractEffect): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.positive_effects.append('Berserk')
        self.stats.HP += 50
        self.stats.Strength += 7
        self.stats.Endurance += 7
        self.stats.Agility += 7
        self.stats.Luck += 7
        self.stats.Intelligence -= 3
        self.stats.Perception -= 3
        self.stats.Charisma -= 3
```

but when i use it, i recive error

```
man = Hero()
man = Berserk(man)
```

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 man = Berserk(man)

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: your berserk class __init__ method only takes in one parameter(self) but you are passing 2, self and man

Comment: Where do you see a "decorator class" here ? or perhaps your definition of "decorator" is totally unrelated to Python's notion of decorator (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) ? If yes you should possibly edit your question's title.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this error is occurring is because the constructor of `Berserk` does not accept an Object of the type `Man`. Therefore, what you must do is change the constructor's arguments, that way you can pass in `Berserk(man)`.

```
class Berserk(AbstractEffect): 
    def __init__(self, man):
        #....
        self.stats.Charisma -= 3
```

Now, since `Berserk(man)` takes 2 arguments, you should not get the error. For more information about constructors, you can check out [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593441/constructors-in-python) that may provide more insight.